# Intent to upload pictures to Picasa

Tags: android, android-intent, picasa

I want to upload pictures to Picasa the easiest way, so I was thinking using an Intent like this:

```
Intent temp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  temp.setType("image/jpeg");
  temp.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  temp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageURI);
  temp.setComponent(new ComponentName(
  "com.google.android.apps.uploader",
  "com.google.android.apps.uploader.picasa.PicasaUploadActivity"));
  startActivityForResult(temp, 0);
```

I´ve been trying to find out how I can create an album or place the picture in a certain album and rename the picture, does anybody know if this is possible and how?

Thanks